# Should Steam Tanks replace your artillery?

Tags: warhammer-total-war

My Empire armies usually have 2-4 artillery pieces - mortars (later replaced), great cannon or Hellstorm (somehow I don't believe in Hellblaster). This works fine, but once the enemy is close, artillery is nearly useless and vulnerable.

Steam tank on on the other hand is amazing in close combat - not only it has heavy armor but also causes fear and terror.

So is there any reason (except the cost: ~500g per tank per round) why I should keep regular artillery instead of tanks?

Edit: Since the Steam Tank doesn't show until the late game, your usual enemy at this stage is usually the Chaos invasion/Norsca with lots of heavy infantry, chariots and hellcannons

Comment: What is your whole army composition? What is the purpose of this specific army? Which enemies do you want to fight with the army? Please provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

Cost is as good a reason as any, cheaper range means you can have more/better units in the front line to hold down the opponent forces longer for your artillery to hit them. Alternatively you can use those extra resources on non-artillery ranged units that provides more reliable damage - though I do not favour empire ranged units.

Most artillery also contains more than one cannon per unit. This gets more obvious as the unit size setting increases. Steam tanks however stays as one tank regardless of unit size, only increasing in health.

Answer (score 1):

Its depend what are you fighting next. If the enemy have artillery, explosive dmg or a lot of range units, you should keep a hellstorm. On the other side if the enemy dont have that and full infantery, its good to have 2-4 tanks.

You should try a combo with full of handgunners, 2-4 tanks, luminark and a light wizard. Also a hellstorm would be good. The enemy just can't get in front of you without dying.